# PDF as mail attachment - Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, sendmail

I want to create a PDF using the barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package and send this with an email as attachment.

The code I have now is:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.factuur', array('factuur' => $factuur));

Mail::queue('emails.factuur', array('factuur' => $factuur), function($message) use ($pdf)
   {
       $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('naam'))->subject('Onderwerp');
       $message->attach($pdf->output());
    });
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only send serializable entities to the queue. This includes Eloquent models etc. But not the PDF view instance. So you will probably need to do the following:

```
Mail::queue('emails.factuur', array('factuur' => $factuur), function($message)
   {
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.factuur', array('factuur' => $factuur));
       $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('naam'))->subject('Onderwerp');
       $message->attach($pdf->output());
    });
```

Comment: You could also swap $message->attach() for $message->attachData() if you want to attach in-memory data as an attachment.